# With AbortOnConnectFail set to false, we still get ConnectTimeout on Azure REDIS

Tags: azure, redis, asp.net-core-2.0, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

We incidentally receive the following error logs in our .NET Core 2.0 Azure App Service:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this operation: GET post:307948:media;
It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). 
To create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. 
ConnectTimeout; IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), 
WORKER: (Busy=20,Free=662,Min=4,Max=682), 
Local-CPU: n/a ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
(It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). 
To create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. ConnectTimeout) 
(UnableToConnect on api-prod.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, 
Initializing, last: NONE, 
origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 12s ago, last-write: 12s ago, 
unanswered-write: 290293s ago, keep-alive: 60s, 
state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, 
last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.0.513.63329)
```

All the answers and blog posts I've found, tell us to set the property **AbortOnConnectFail** to false. We already have this property set to false, and still these errors occur. Here is our implementation:

```
public class CacheService : ICacheService
    {
        private static IRedisConfiguration _redisConfiguration;
        private readonly IDateService _dateService;

        private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection =
            new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
            {
                var configurationOptions = CreateConfigurationOptions();
                return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configurationOptions);
            });

        public CacheService(IRedisConfiguration redisConfiguration, IDateService dateService)
        {
            _redisConfiguration = redisConfiguration;
            _dateService = dateService;
        }

        private static ConfigurationOptions CreateConfigurationOptions()
        {
            var deltaBackOffInMilliseconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Milliseconds;
            var maxDeltaBackOffInMilliseconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20).Milliseconds;

            var config = new ConfigurationOptions();

            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#azure-redis-cache-retry-guidelines
            config.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
            config.ConnectRetry = 3;
            config.ConnectTimeout = 2000;
            config.ReconnectRetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(deltaBackOffInMilliseconds, maxDeltaBackOffInMilliseconds);

            config.EndPoints.Add(_redisConfiguration.HostName);
            config.Password = _redisConfiguration.Password;
            config.Ssl = _redisConfiguration.Ssl;
            config.DefaultDatabase = _redisConfiguration.DatabaseId;

            return config;
        }

        public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection => LazyConnection.Value;

        public static IDatabase Cache => Connection.GetDatabase();
}
```

On the Azure App service I've checked the TCP connections, and no warnings are shown. There was an increase of **outgoing connections**, but it was below 1000.

With two instances of the API running, we have about 80 connections, almost constant. No increase over the day, so it seams connection management seems right.

Any tips on how to resolve this? Perhaps it's due to some more configuration tweaks.

Azure Redis: P1 Premium tier
StackExchange.Redis version: 2.0.513
.NET Core API running on .NET Core 2.0

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issues. Were you able to find solution for this?

Comment: @RobertVuković no. Not yet.

Comment: You probably should adjust your thread pool settings if busy worker threads are set to 20 and min is set to 4. .NET Thread Pool threads enter a .5 second waiting period to wait for a thread to become available before spawning a new one. This would effectively stall background threads (and potentially increase timeouts).

As for your question. Ultimately, if the client can't connect, it can't connect.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know that you got an answer for your solution but if you havent and if you are using redis cache in azure for non-ssl, maybe you have to activate it as follow in the picture.  [image]